# magento - make customer's company mandatory in admin screens

Tags: magento, field

I am trying to make company name mandatory in Magento CE1.7. I have found many of the front end places to make changes, but I am not able to find the related files to modify in the backend admin panel.

link in admin console:
/admin/customer/edit/id/68/...

here are the related front end files that I have identified for changes.

```
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\address.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\address\edit.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml
```

related link - for front end...
ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456794/magento-make-the-field-company-required

Comment: you answered your own question! have you checked the accepted solution of that related link question?

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this through the backend - specifically the database.

Going to **Admin -> Customers -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Address Attributes** will show you the company field. Once you click in, you can see the required field however as this is a system attribute the **'Values Required'** field is **disabled**.

You can override this by either using your developer toolbar and removing the **disabeld="disabled"** attribute from the select tag *or*, you can go to the database directly and go to the table **eav_attribute**. Then look for company under **attribute_code** and change **is_required** from 0 to 1.

Comment: Looks great, but is this available on 1.7CE. I don;t have Admin->Customers on this edition.

Comment: Login to the backend, you will see a Customers drop-down menu.

Comment: this is what I see: Customers ->  Manage Customers |  Customer Groups | Online Customers.  The EE version seems to come with this feature... http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/manage-customer-attributes

Comment: Then perhaps go directly to the database as I have mentioned later on in my answer.